# De que maneira eu poderia arrumar esse código para que ele imprimisse os números do vetor de forma crescente?

Tags: c, array

```
    //Questão 4
#include <stdio.h>
#define TAM 10
int main()
{
    int i, valorVET, VET[TAM];
    printf("Digite os 10 numeros:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < TAM; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &VET[i]);
    }
    for(i = TAM - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if(i != 0)
        {
            if(VET[i] <= VET[i - 1])
            {
                valorVET = VET[i];
                VET[i] = VET[i - 1];
                VET[i - 1] = valorVET;
            }
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < TAM; i++)
    {
        if(i != 0)
        {
            if(VET[i] > VET[i + 1])
            {
                valorVET = VET[i];
                VET[i] = VET[i + 1];
                VET[i + 1] = valorVET;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(i = 0; i < TAM; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", VET[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Dá algum erro ? Não ordena como quer ?

Comment: Não dá erro, só não está ordenando na ordem crescente

Comment: Para fazer a ordenação você precisa de um `for` dentro de outro, ou seja `fors` aninhados, isto é seguindo algoritmos de ordenação simples como o *selection sort* ou *bubble sort*

Comment: E como eu ficaria isso? Pode me dizer?

Comment: Eu colocaria o outro for de comparação dentro do primeiro ou fazia outro for com logica diferente?

Comment: Sugiro que pegue do principio e siga a ideia do algoritmo, percebendo bem como funciona, e depois passe então para a implementação. Tem por exemplo [aqui na wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) referencias para o bubble sort, que é o mais parecido com o que estava a fazer no código. Tem também outros algoritmos de ordenação diferentes com as suas particularidades

Comment: Tudo bem, muito obrigado!!